# Dummy function to test parallelizing methods in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Say you want to test different parallelizations of an algorithm, removing some details of the algorithm to focus only on structural aspects. For instance, you recognize that the original algorithm applies the same function on a graph (or on a list, a grid, etc.), so you want to remove the details of the original function and put a cpu-intensive dummy one that takes the same time (let's say you can estimate such time). Which dummy function would you use in python to simulate cpu evaluation?

I have seen use of sleep() but since it is not cpu-intensive I believe the results of different parallelizations could be misleading due to clever scheduling.

Comment: I do not think there are any general answer for that. It entirely depends on what you want to simulate. `sleep` is bad to simulate computations but is fine to simulate blocking IO tasks. For computational tasks, some are memory bound, and some are not. These tasks can behave very differently because of the (shared) RAM contention. Using a function not representative of your application will lead to misleading results. The best function is the real one. You need to find a trade-off between the two and this is highly dependent of your specific needs/goals.

Comment: Indeed as you say parallelization is a complex matter, but say I want to neglect memory constraints and focus only on the time evaluation. For instance, if I want to create a MWE, of course I need to simplify things since the original algorithm may be too complex. Is there a cpu intensive dummy function that come to your mind?

Comment: AFAIK, no. If you just want to keep a thread busy, a simply way is to do an active polling like: `start = time(); while time()<(start+delay): pass`. Note that `time()` should lock the CPython GIL.